# Scrapy closed spider which still got jobs

Tags: python, scrapy

```
2017-10-17 11:48:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
29957 2017-10-17 11:48:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
29958 {'downloader/request_bytes': 2175351,
29959  'downloader/request_count': 6472,
29960  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6472,
29961  'downloader/response_bytes': 494012842,
29962  'downloader/response_count': 6472,
29963  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 6419,
29964  'downloader/response_status_count/301': 53,
29965  'dupefilter/filtered': 8,
29966  'finish_reason': 'finished',
29967  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 17, 11, 48, 19, 59301),
29968  'item_scraped_count': 6417,
29969  'log_count/DEBUG': 12891,
29970  'log_count/ERROR': 1,
29971  'log_count/INFO': 120,
29972  'memusage/max': 385605632,
29973  'memusage/startup': 94334976,
29974  'request_depth_max': 1,
29975  'response_received_count': 6419,
29976  'scheduler/dequeued': 6471,
29977  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6471,
29978  'scheduler/enqueued': 6471,
29979  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6471,
29980  'spider_exceptions/RuntimeError': 1,
29981  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 17, 9, 55, 15, 21744)}
29982 2017-10-17 11:48:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

As u can see, my spider only did 6472 jobs but actually I have 228336 jobs to do, but it just closed.
I am crawling a property website, and each property has a id number. I crawled 228336 house ID and store in a file. And this spider is to verify these ID(this step is succeeded)

The thing is I don't know why it's closed without finish all the jobs,

```
def parse(self, response):
          print("number of the id_dict is %s"%len(self.house_id_dict))
          for n in self.house_id_dict.keys():    #house ID eg.44225621 
              yield response.follow("/for-sale/details/"+n, callback=self.parse_house)
          print("yield all the links!")
```

The keys are house IDs. And it doesn't even print the last line...
I am going to mad....

Comment: check that you have 8 filtered requests, and 53 redirects (301 statuses), so maybe you are losing some data or requests there. Scrapy filters duplicated requests by default, so if you are making GET requests (only urls) check if those urls are not the same on some cases.

Comment: There was an exception raised, the log count reports one error `'log_count/ERROR': 1,` and near the end of the log it says `'spider_exceptions/RuntimeError': 1,` - can you find that error earlier in your log? This may have caused the sider to stop.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not the problem why it closed I think, the error is the dict size changed during iteration. Because I delete the item(house_id) in dict when it shows that the house is sold.